# Laravel7 How to custom the RegisterController to save multiple data when user selected

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-controller

I am a newbie in Laravel and I need your help.

I'm using the Laravel 7. I have 3 tables in my database.

1. **User** to save the registered users
2. **Categories** to show in the front-end that I provided for them to choose (multiple)
3. **Vendor_Cat** that I collecting the user_id and category_id after the user registered

**Here are my Models**

```
public function users(){
        return $this->BelongsToMany(User::class);
    }

public function categories(){
        return $this->BelongsToMany(Categories::class);
    }
```

**This one below is my VendorCategories Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'category_id',
    'vendor_id'
];
```

And this is the Laravel RegisterController

```
   protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'tel' => $data['tel'],
            'lineid'=> isset($data['lineid']) ? $data['lineid'] : null,
        ]);
```

**My Front-End code (Just Categories for a user to choose)**

```
                        @if($categories->count()>0)
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                            <select class="selectpicker col-sm-12 md-12" id="selectpicker"  name="categories[]" multiple data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count" data-count-selected-text="Selected Categories({0})" title="Choose your catories" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" required>
                            @foreach ($categories as $categories)
                            <option class="com-sm-4 md-4" aria-expanded="false" value="{{$categories->id}}"
                                @if (isset($user))
                                  @if($user->hasCat($catgories->id))
                                      selected
                                  @endif
                                @endif
                                ><strong>{{Str::limit($categories->name,51)}}</strong></option>
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('category_id')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        @endif
```

**Full Register Form Code**

```
                <form class="form-detail col-xs-12 sm-12" action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="tabcontent" id="sign-up">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="text" id="full_name" class="input-text @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                                <span class="label">Full Name</span>
                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                                  <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="text" id="your_email" class="input-text @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                <span class="label">E-Mail</span>
                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                                <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="text" id="yournumber" class="input-text @error('tel') is-invalid @enderror" name="tel" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <span class="label">Telephone Number</span>
                                @error('tel')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                                <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-text @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <span class="label">Password</span>
                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                                <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="password" id="comfirm_password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <span class="label">Confirm Password</span>
                                <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                                <input type="text" id="comfirm_password_1" class="input-text @error('lineid') is-invalid @enderror" name="lineid" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <span class="label">Line Id</span>
                                @error('lineid')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                                <span class="border"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        @if($categories->count()>0)
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-row-inner">
                            <select class="selectpicker col-sm-12 md-12" id="selectpicker"  name="categories[]" multiple data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count" data-count-selected-text="หมวดหมู่ที่เลือก ({0} หมวดหมู่)" title="เลือกหมวดหมู่ที่ให้บริการ" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" required>
                            @foreach ($categories as $categories)
                            <option class="com-sm-4 md-4" aria-expanded="false" value="{{$categories->id}}"
                                @if (isset($user))
                                  @if($user->hasCat($catgories->id))
                                      selected
                                  @endif
                                @endif
                                ><strong>{{Str::limit($categories->name,51)}}</strong></option>
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('category_id')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback-detail" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        @endif
                     <div class="form-row-last">
                        <input type="submit" name="register" class="register">
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**If I want to save the category Ids that I use @foreach to show in the Register Form after the users selected. What should I do?**

**This is the thing that I have tried before**

```
protected function create(array $data){
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'tel' => $data['tel'],
            'lineid'=> isset($data['lineid']) ? $data['lineid'] : null,
        ]);

    $vendor_cat = VendorCat::create([
            'category_id' => $data['category'],
            'vendor_id' => $user->id
        ]);

    return $user;
}
```

**Here is the explanation image**
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OonLe.png)

Thank you,

p.s. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what about submitting a form to send the selected value to the controller

Comment: What did you mean sir? This one ?
<div class="form-row-last">
     <input type="submit" name="register" class="register" >           
</div>

Comment: I am asking are you not passing it with other form input values for register form? with <form> tags

Comment: I put user data with categories that I provided for them to choose in the same form and I have tried to add more code in the RegisterController but it can't solve my problem. I added it to my topic already. Please help sir. I have tried to solve this almost the whole week.

Comment: so ybasically you want to save some data to VendorCat after data is saved in User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `registered` method in your RegisterController, to override the register method from your `RegistersUsers` trait. Also add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your RegisterController.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
        // .... your create method in RegisterController
}
protected function registered( Request $request, $user )
{
    VendorCat::create([
            'category_id' => $request['category'],
            'vendor_id' => $user->id
        ]);
}
```

EDIT:

as you are getting `categories` as array, you can simply store all the keys separated by commas, or store them separately for each values,

#### To store them separately,

```
foreach($request['categories'] as $category){
    VendorCat::create([
            'category_id' => $category,
            'vendor_id' => $user->id
        ]);
}
```

It will create 3 columns for 3 different category_id with same vendor_id.

#### To store using commas,

```
VendorCat::create([
            'category_id' => is_array($request['categories']) ? implode(",",$request['categories']) : $request['categories'],
            'vendor_id' => $user->id
        ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The table "Vendor_Cat" already got the user_id but the category_id is null.

Comment: I can't put the code in the comment. 
This is an image of my RegisterController https://ibb.co/8P1HXXf
And this one is an image of the datable.
https://ibb.co/RG8bd1H
Please help me to solve this sir. You are my hope.

Comment: can you check whats inside $request, you can try `dd($request);` just as you enter the registered() function

Comment: +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:12 [▼
      "_token" => "9kydKabp1r65ZL5XBOERx8PfCvUolyPxSEIaJbtL"
      "name" => "test8"
      "email" => "test@gmail.com"
      "password" => "test33333"
      "password_confirmation" => "0123456789"
      "tel" => "0123456789"
      "lineid" => "test8"
      "categories" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "3"
        1 => "4"
        2 => "5"
      ]
    ]
  }

Comment: also see if you have added `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your controller

Comment: It looks like it is receiving data but not stored in the database.

Comment: there is no `category` key it is `categories` in the $request from the data you have sent in above comment

Comment: to store categories as it is an array, you can store it with `,` using implode,  will update the answer

Comment: OMG! what should I do next? I'm dead.

Comment: updated the answer check with whatever method suitable to you

Comment: Thank you so much! That’s very kind of you. It wasn't just solved my problem but also explain it to me.